# SQL: Get daily/weekly/monthly consumption of electric meter by SQL-Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL-table (called Item1) with two columns:
"Time" [datetime] and "Value" [float]. Every 5 Minutes the total amount of my electric meter is appended to the data table, like that:

```
| Time                | Value         |
| 2018-07-22 21:55:00 | 202660.199951 |
| 2018-07-22 22:00:00 | 202673.899902 |
| 2018-07-22 22:05:00 | 202684.699951 |
| 2018-07-22 22:10:00 | 202691.534534 |
| 2018-07-22 22:15:00 | 202710.334253 |
```

How can I calculate the power consumption per day / week / month with one sql-query, getting the results as a new table. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Item1 WHERE HOUR(Time)=0 AND MINUTE(Time)=0
```

which gives me the values every midnight, but how can i subtract these values?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `join`:

```
select date(i.time), i.value, iprev.value,
       (i.value - iprev.value) as diff
from item_1 i left join
     item_1 iprev
     on date(iprev.time) = date(i.time) - interval 1 day and
        hour(iprev.time) = 0 and minute(iprev.time) = 0
where hour(i.time) = 0 and minute(i.time) = 0
group by date(i.time), i.value, iprev.value;
```

You would change the timeframe for `iprev` to get differences of weeks or months.

Comment: Fantastic. It works. Thank you very much for your help.